# Vb.net formatting string in columns

Tags: vb.net, string, format, tabular

I load 3 fields data from database and want to display them in a text box in columns format. I have tried to use padLeft and string.Format but every time data are not displayed in proper columns. Would some one please guide me, thank you.

Comment: `TextBox` does not have columns.  Are there multiple rows of data?  If so, why not use a `DataGridView` or similar control, that do display tabular data?

Comment: `ListBox` and `ListView` will also be a good idea, as @Tim suggested.

Comment: Yes, I do have multiple rows of data. I dont want to use datagridview in my case, I just want to display data in textbox in proper columns.

Comment: I want to format the info that will be displayed in a treeview in columns. It means when I click the + sign I will get 3 column data from database displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose a monospaced font like **consolas**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it will be better to use `DataGridView` instead of `TextBox`. But if you really want to to display data in `TextBox`, you can use concatenation. 
e.g
    Dim data1, data2, data2, result As String

```
data1 = field1.ToString() 
data2 = field2.ToString() 
data3 = field3.ToString() 

result = data1 + data2 + data3
resultTextBox.Text = result
```

Comment: But here if the data have different number of characters it would not be displayed in proper columns

Comment: then use ListView or DataGridView.

Comment: What if I want to do this when I press the + sign in treeview? can this be accomplished?